# Is that a good idea to use static variable in presenter that is declared in my Application class

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

Hi am using MVP pattern in my android application. I have some static method in application class that check for connectivity status.

```
public class AppModule extends Application {

  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

I Am using that application level static method in presenter to check for internet connection.

```
public class ActivityWallPresenter {

private CreatrixTestCall creatrixTestCall;

@Inject
public ActivityWallPresenter(CreatrixTestCall creatrixTestCall) {
    this.creatrixTestCall = creatrixTestCall;
}

public void loadPosts(ActivityWallFragmentContract activityWallFragment) {
    this.fragmentContract = activityWallFragment;
    if (AppModule.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        fragmentContract.showProgress();
        callWeb();
    } else {
        fragmentContract.onNetworkDisconnected();
    }
}
```

Is that a good idea of calling a static method? suggest me any other approach if not.

Comment: Though it is just a static method you can place it here but the good coding technique is to place it in a separate class which may be utils.java or globalMethods.java or any of your choice.

Comment: Depends on what you define as a 'good idea'. As long as you don't assign any variables to static members, I don't think there much harm to it. However, I see that you are using a variable `context` in that static function. If that is an instance of an `Activity`, that object will never be garbage collected, causing a (sort of) memory leak

Comment: It depends on assumptions, you can make to your code. If you want to use true OOP approach, you have to create a class that checks connectivity by given context and then inject it in your presenter. But if you can have procedures in your code, then static method is best approach, I think. Second question is, where to place this static function

Comment: You may need to read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html, >Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), include Context.getApplicationContext() as a Context argument when invoking your singleton's getInstance() method.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply... here i have used application class for third party support lib initiation along with the some of the static methods.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a well understandable code, if you are using any `public static` methods then write it in separate class.

Not need to write it in `Application` class.

And I think `Application` class is to start certain things like analytics Multidex etc. since the application class is started before `Activities` or `Services` are being run, And I mostly use `Application` class for initialising `Multidex`.

So It will be best to create another class like `Utils.java` for `public static` Method.

Comment: Agreed, plus then you can make a 'utils' package where you start to collect them(as your project grows in complexity). Here is an example of an assignment I recently wrote where we had a ton of 'utils' files throughout the application before refactoring. After putting them all into their own package, it really helped clean up the code.
https://gitlab.com/vandy-aad-2/aad-2-assg-2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/vandy/mooc/assignments/framework/utils